# Foreach returns only last element, but it was working before

Tags: php, loops, foreach, concatenation

I have a foreach loop and it worked at beginning, but after reloading the page I'm getting only last element. Here's code

```
$exploded = explode(" ",$someString);
            foreach ($exploded as $word) {
                $sentence = " this is $word";
            }
            echo $sentence;
```

At first I got a long string that consisted of repeating "this is" and unique $word, but now I'm getting only one "this is" and the last $word. It's important  to me that the whole thing will be as variable because I'll need to use that string later.

Comment: Put your echo statement in your foreach loop or use concatenation to make it one string

Comment: I know that will work but I need the whole string to be specifically in a variable.

Comment: So put it in a variable

Comment: Sorry, but did you read whole code? Foreach is putting the string in a $sentence variable but for some reason only the last element from array.

Comment: And that reason is because you didn't do what I said in my first comment. So, yes, I did read the whole code. It was a mistake caused by not knowing basic PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$exploded = explode(" ", $someString);
$sentence = '';
foreach ($exploded as $word) {
    $sentence .= $word;
}
echo $sentence;
```

Comment: This solved problem that occured when I used previous answer. Thanks. Turns out you have to set empty string before assigning concatenation or else you'll get notice.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the $sentence variable with each iteration of the loop. Instead of:

```
$sentence = " this is $word";
```

You must concatenate $sentence with the new string:

```
$sentence .= " this is $word";
```

Comment: Thanks! Works now. There's only one little problem now. PHP outputs now proper string BUT also error Undefined variable: sentence (on line $sentence .= " this is $word";). Why?